# Do you need to add a ref on every component if you want to interact with React components as DOM elems?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dom

I'm an experienced backend programmer, although I'm new to React.  I'm working on adding functionality to our system to track impressions of video thumbnails.  It turns out that at my company, there is code which already exists to achieve this, but it is tightly-coupled with identifying DOM elements and CSS selectors (to track an impression of a specific image, for example).

I would love to integrate the code we already have to achieve my own goal, and I'm dealing with React components, functions and classes.  I've done a ton of research already, and it looks as though to identify a React component as a DOM element, that component needs a "ref".

My question is: suppose that one is starting a project from scratch. Is it advisable when writing React code to put refs on (almost) every component?  I can't find a clear answer to this from my research...the best I can find is "yes, if you will be manipulating those components as DOM elements at some point".  But, if you don't know in advance if you will need to access those elements in the DOM, is it better to just add a ref from the start?

I'm asking this question because I'm concerned that if I want to integrate this code to track impressions which relies on DOM elements, then I may need to refactor some of our existing code to include refs, and I'm not sure if this is an anti-pattern in React terms (for instance, if I were to add refs to *every* component in our codebase...would that be inadvisable, or is that more common in the React paradigm?).

Answer (score 2):

React devs advise using refs as little as possible, since mutating them will not automatically rerender a component. It also undermines the "immutability" of data.

From: https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#best-practices-for-dom-manipulation-with-refs

> Refs are an escape hatch. You should only use them when you have to “step outside React”. Common examples of this include managing focus, scroll position, or calling browser APIs that React does not expose.
>
> If you stick to non-destructive actions like focusing and scrolling, you shouldn’t encounter any problems. However, if you try to modify the DOM manually, you can risk conflicting with the changes React is making.

From: https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs#differences-between-refs-and-state

> Perhaps you’re thinking refs seem less “strict” than state—you can mutate them instead of always having to use a state setting function, for instance. But in most cases, you’ll want to use state. Refs are an “escape hatch” you won’t need often.

To answer your question: No, it is not advisable to use refs unless you have a specific reason to do so.

Comment: Super-helpful thoughts!  Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I edited a lot out to just include quotes from the devs - they really describe it best. The two links there will probably be very useful for you.